# Why can a new user select from any table?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, permissions, access-control

When I create a user in Postgres,

```
create user test with password 'test';
```

The user ends up being able to connect to every database in the instance.  The user can also select from any table:

```
# psql -h localhost testdb test
Password for user test: *****
psql (8.4.20, server 9.1.13)
WARNING: psql version 8.4, server version 9.1.
         Some psql features might not work.
Type "help" for help.

testdb=> select * from testtable;
 id
------------
      1
(1 row)
```

The `\l` database listing shows that `testdb` has empty `Access privileges`.  So why can a newly created user connect to that database?

The newly created "test" user can also select data from tables.  Why can he do so without a `grant` of `select` privileges?

I'd like to create a user that can only connect to one database and only read from certain views.  How can I prevent a user from reading directly from tables?

Comment: This closely related answer on SO should be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918367/grant-privileges-for-a-particular-database-in-postgresql/24923877#24923877

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: Thanks.  Is it true that if `\l` or `\dn+` displays empty access privileges, that is the same as `postgres=UC/postgres, =UC/postgres` ?

Comment: That wouldn't fit in a comment. I added an answer (note the clarifications on db / schema).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address the question of why test can `SELECT` from tables without a `GRANT`, it is because you have not explicitly run `REVOKE` for the ability to connect to your database(s) from `PUBLIC`, and then explicitly run `GRANT` for your `test` user:

```
REVOKE connect ON DATABASE testdb FROM PUBLIC;
GRANT connect ON DATABASE testdb TO test;
```

Once that is done, you would `REVOKE SELECT` for your user within that database your tables and other items you wish to prevent the user from accessing, and then explicitly `GRANT SELECT` for the views.

Note that user here could also be role, which multiple users could then be added to.

Comment: Thanks.  I won't be able to revoke privileges from public as that would affect other users.  Is there a way to deny rights to a particular user, in effect overruling the grant from public?

Comment: After `revoke connect on database testdb from test`, the test user can still connect to testdb.  It seems you can't overrule grants from public then?

Comment: @Andomar `REVOKE` means "take away a grant". You'd want a `DENY` rule, i.e. "explicitly disallow what would otherwise be allowed", but PostgreSQL doesn't have them. So you *must* `REVOKE` from `public` then grant the rights back to the users/groups who require it.

Comment: Even if you do not know all the users that may need to connect to a DB, if you can enforce that they be added to a role granted connect other than public, that should not prove difficult.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>Also addressing the question in the comments.</sup>

#### Role `public`

[Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-grant.html)

> The key word `PUBLIC` indicates that the privileges are to be granted
>   to all roles, including those that might be created later. `PUBLIC`
>   can be thought of as an implicitly defined group that **always includes
>   all roles**.

Bold emphasis mine. Membership in `public` cannot be revoked (or granted). You can only revoke privileges from `public`. In your case, to block out all roles without explicit privileges, like [@Robert already provided](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/73011/3684):

```
REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE testdb FROM PUBLIC;
```

#### Role `postgres`

The database role `postgres` is a `superuser` by default. You can take that away from `postgres` - but that would be unwise: everybody (including some client programs) expects `postgres` to be a superuser. You can also create more superusers (careful with that!). Superusers don't need privileges. [The manual once more](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-grant.html):

> It should be noted that database superusers can access all objects
>   regardless of object privilege settings. This is comparable to the
>   rights of root in a Unix system. As with root, it's unwise to operate
>   as a superuser except when absolutely necessary.

#### As to your question:

> Is it true that if `\l` or `\dn+` displays empty access privileges, that
>   is the same as `postgres=UC/postgres, =UC/postgres`

Not exactly.

- Privileges are granted by the owner or a superuser (or a role that was granted the privilege to do so). `postgres=UC/postgres` would mean `postgres` granted it, which is not accurate for empty privileges, but the effect is the same in a default installation.
- However, `public` gets **no privileges for new schemas** and only `CONNECT` and `TEMP` (can create temporary tables) privileges **for databases** by default, *not* the `CREATE` privilege (cannot create schemas). That would be something like `=UT/??` according to the list of possible privileges - [the manual once more](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-grant.html):

```
        r -- SELECT ("read")
        w -- UPDATE ("write")
        a -- INSERT ("append")
        d -- DELETE
        D -- TRUNCATE
        x -- REFERENCES
        t -- TRIGGER
        X -- EXECUTE
        U -- USAGE
        C -- CREATE
        c -- CONNECT
        T -- TEMPORARY
  arwdDxt -- ALL PRIVILEGES (for tables, varies for other objects)
        * -- grant option for preceding privilege
```

You can change default privileges. I wrote more about that in the related answer mentioned in the comments:

- [Grant privileges for a particular database in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918367/grant-privileges-for-a-particular-database-in-postgresql/24923877#24923877))

But those default privileges only apply objects created *after* defaults were changed. So what does an empty ACL entry mean? [The manual on the system catalog `pg_default_acl`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-default-acl.html):

> Note that **when an ACL entry in another catalog is null, it is taken to
>   represent the hard-wired default privileges** for its object, not
>   whatever might be in pg_default_acl at the moment.

Bold emphasis mine.