# Grant access to all tables of a database

Tags: postgresql, best-practices, permissions, access-control

I recently wanted to share regular access rights with one user of a server and I realized that a simple `CREATE USER` and `GRANT ALL ON DATABASE` commands didn't let him run a simple `SELECT` on the data.

I would like to grant rights to all tables from a given database to a specified user, but I am not sure if it is the best idea to grant him access to whole schema `public` as I don't know if it would allow some kind of privilege escalation. Is there any other way?

Comment: Why can't you just `GRANT SELECT ON TableName TO [Domain\User]`? I usually just assign users to the `db_datareader` role if all they need is read access to all the tables but I'm not sure how granular you want to be.

Comment: I'd like to grant all CRUD to all tables in the database. Also, DROPping and CREATEing inside of this database could also prove useful.

Answer (score 30):

#### Postgres 14

... adds the predefined role `pg_read_all_data` to make this simple:

```
GRANT pg_read_all_data TO myuser;
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/predefined-roles.html)

> `pg_read_all_data`
>
> Read all data (tables, views, sequences), as if having `SELECT` rights
> on those objects, and `USAGE` rights on all schemas, even without
> having it explicitly. This role does not have the role attribute
> `BYPASSRLS` set. If RLS is being used, an administrator may wish to
> set `BYPASSRLS` on roles which this role is `GRANT`ed to.

#### For older versions

The privilege on `DATABASE` only grants general connection rights to the database and no more. A user with just that privilege can only see what the general public is allowed to see.

To grant read access to *all tables*, you also need privileges on all schemas and tables:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO myuser; -- more schemas?
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO myuser;
```

You may also want to set default privileges for **future** schemas and tables. Run for every role that creates objects in your db

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE mycreating_user IN SCHEMA public
GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO myuser;
```

But you really need to [understand the whole concept](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/user-manag.html) first.
And it's almost always better to bundle privileges in group roles and then grant/revoke the group role to/from user roles. Related:

- [Why can a new user select from any table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73010/why-can-a-new-user-select-from-any-table/73122#73122)
- [How to grant all privileges on views to arbitrary user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10491275/939860)
- [Grant privileges for a particular database in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24923877/939860)
- [How to manage DEFAULT PRIVILEGES for USERs on a DATABASE vs SCHEMA?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117109/how-to-manage-default-privileges-for-users-on-a-database-vs-schema/117661#117661)

Comment: Is `myusr` a typo? Shouldn't it be `myuser`?

Comment: @attomos: It's supposed to be a different user in the example. I clarified.

Comment: You must connect to the desired database for this to work, either issuing `\c some_db` first or by specifying the database in the command line. I was doing `su - postgres psq` and the commands were not working for me because I was on the wrong database

Comment: I wish there was a `GRANT ... ON ALL TABLES IN DATABASE foo ...` but it seems that it does not