# How to allow user access to non-owned objects in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, postgresql-9.5, access-control

I am in the process of creating a pre-prod Postgres database, and want to ensure the accessing user has limited access.

I want to setup tables in such a way that the accessing user can't `CREATE`, `DROP` or `ALTER` objects. Currently the only way I can see it to change the ownership to another user, such as `postgres` and then somehow grant only the permissions needed:

```
 ALTER TABLE mytable SET OWNER TO postgres;
 REVOKE connect ON DATABASE mydatabase FROM PUBLIC;
 GRANT USAGE, SELECT, UPDATE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO dbuser;
 GRANT connect ON DATABASE mydatabase TO dbuser;
```

The issue is when I do the above I am unable to do a simple `SELECT` when I connect with the user the grant was applied to. For example:

```
 select * from mytable;
```

Yields:

> ```
> ERROR:  permission denied for relation mytable
> ```

How to get this right?
Additionally, should I use a named schema other than `public`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Read the [manual on `GRANT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html) and [`ALTER TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html).
2. There is no `USAGE` privilege for tables. You would see an error message if you tried your `GRANT` command.
3. You need permissions on the ***schema***, too. Here `USAGE` is right. But you certainly want to revoke `CREATE`.
4. Ownership for sequences that are *owned* by `serial` columns is changed to the new table owner automatically. But any other sequences you'll need to reown manually. Or you go a more aggressive route with [`REASSIGN OWNED`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-reassign-owned.html).
5. You *may* need permissions on sequences, too. (If you grant `INSERT` or want them to use `currval()` or `nextval()` functions). Those are currently (v9.6) separate from table permissions.
6. I strongly suggest to bundle permissions in a *group* role and grant / revoke membership in that role to selected user roles.

Something along these lines, as superuser:

```
REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE mydatabase FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;                      -- you may or may not want this
-- REVOKE ALL ON ALL TABLES    IN SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;  -- only for more existing permissions
-- REVOKE ALL ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;  -- only for more existing permissions

ALTER TABLE mytable OWNER TO postgres;    -- or some admin role. best keep the superuser out of this
-- more tables? or even:
-- REASSIGN OWNED BY dbuser TO postgres;  -- to reassign *all* owned objects the current DB

CREATE ROLE usr_permissions;
GRANT usr_permissions TO dbuser;

GRANT CONNECT        ON DATABASE mydatabase            TO usr_permissions;
GRANT USAGE          ON SCHEMA public                  TO usr_permissions;  -- if you revoked from PUBLIC
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON ALL TABLES    IN SCHEMA public TO usr_permissions;  -- DELETE, INSERT?
GRANT USAGE          ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO usr_permissions;  -- if you also granted INSERT
```

Related:

- [How to manage DEFAULT PRIVILEGES for USERs on a DATABASE vs SCHEMA?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117109/how-to-manage-default-privileges-for-users-on-a-database-vs-schema/117661#117661)
- [Grant access to all tables of a database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91953/grant-access-to-all-tables-of-a-database/91974#91974)

> Additionally, should I use a named schema other than public?

The schema `public` is in no way special. It only happens to be installed by default with permissions for `PUBLIC` and preset in the default [`search_path`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860). Some DB admins even delete it. You can use it like any other schema. Depends on the complete situation. Related:

- [Is it recommended to install extensions into pg_catalog schema?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107389/is-it-recommended-to-install-extensions-into-pg-catalog-schema/107418#107418)

Comment: can't edit less than 6 characters, but the alter table owner query should be `ALTER TABLE mytable OWNER TO postgres` (no `SET`)

Comment: Thank you! Fixed.