# Postgresql 9.6, create a user with only select permissions for a given database/schema

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I want to create a user that has:

- has its default privileges revoked when I create it
- can only perform selects against a given database/schema

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Just issue the right `GRANT`s.

Answer (score 0):

Please read below mentioned official documentation from `Postgres`

Official Documentation of `REVOKE`:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-revoke.html

Official Documentation of `GRANT`:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-grant.html

To grant `select` privilege to schema you need to run following query

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema_name TO user_name;
```

For more details read following Post

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91953/grant-access-to-all-tables-of-a-database