# When are privileges listed in \l and when not?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, psql

When are access privileges listed by \l, and when are they not?  The access privileges listed by \l can change after a grant and revoke:

```
$ createuser -EP my_readonly
$ psql development
development=# \l
                                           List of databases
            Name             |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------------------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 development                 | vagrant  | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | 
...
development=# grant usage on schema public to my_readonly;
development=# grant connect on database development to my_readonly;
development=# \l
                                             List of databases
            Name             |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |     Access privileges      
-----------------------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+----------------------------
 development                 | vagrant  | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | =Tc/vagrant               +
                             |          |          |             |             | vagrant=CTc/vagrant       +
                             |          |          |             |             | my_readonly=c/vagrant
...
development=# revoke connect on database development from my_readonly;
REVOKE
development=# revoke usage on schema public from my_readonly;
REVOKE
development=# \l
                                           List of databases
            Name             |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------------------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 development                 | vagrant  | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | =Tc/vagrant          +
                             |          |          |             |             | vagrant=CTc/vagrant
```

Why is that?  What state changed?  I believe the my_readonly user's ability to connect was unchanged through this whole psql session (because I'm guessing the PUBLIC role has connect privileges), but clearly *something* changed: what is that thing?

Side question: how can I explicitly ask postgres whether PUBLIC in fact *does* have connect privileges (they may have been revoked -- see [Why can a new user select from any table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73010/why-can-a-new-user-select-from-any-table/))?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The backslash commands in psql are shortcuts for a query or queries that look through the system catalogs. The `\l` command looks at information in `pg_catalog.pg_database`, specifically, this query:

```
SELECT d.datname as "Name",
   pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(d.datdba) as "Owner",
   pg_catalog.pg_encoding_to_char(d.encoding) as "Encoding",
   d.datcollate as "Collate",
   d.datctype as "Ctype",
   pg_catalog.array_to_string(d.datacl, E'\n') AS "Access privileges"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_database d
ORDER BY 1;
```

You can make `psql` show what it is using for the backslash commands by passing the `-E` flag to it when you invoke it on the command line.

If the permissions on a database or other object are the defaults that PostgreSQL creates them with, the `*acl` column will be `NULL`. If you change the defaults, as you have, the ACL column will be populated with information related to the `GRANT` and/or `REVOKE` statements you have ran.

You can see the permissions/ACLs specifically via either `\z` or `\dp`

If you read further here:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-grant.html

If you scroll down, (or search for the word `psql`), you can look at the table that shows you how to interpret the ACLs that you see with `\l` or in an ACL column.

For example:

`=Tc/vagrant`

means that PUBLIC (the implicit role that contains all roles) has permissions to create temporary tables `T` and connect `c`, because the ACL line `=xxxxx` denotes permissions applied to PUBLIC, while `rolname=xxxx` applies to that specific role.

This presentation from Dalibo should also help clarify this further: [Managing Rights in PostgreSQL](http://wiki.postgresql.org/images/d/d1/Managing_rights_in_postgresql.pdf)

Hope that helps. =)

Comment: But could you name the default that was changed after `GRANT`/`REVOKE`? How can I see default values that were hidden by `\l`?